# Add Timer to Custom Control to make a Blinking Cursor

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, controls, custom-controls

Somehow I manage to get myself in a place again where neither Google or my Wording of my problem gives me a solution.

So, to put it this way, I'm creating a `TextBox` from scratch, derived from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`. I have so far been able to draw the `Text` variable, and also added editing functionality to it (Like a normal `TextBox` usually do).

The idea of the dreadful time-consuming exercise is to create my own library of custom controls that have maximum theme-capabilities for use with the software I develop.

So, my problem: **Drawing the blinking cursor in the `TextBox`.**

I'm able to draw a static Line, which moves left to right depending on where the `CursorPosition` takes it. Added a timer to the control (hence the `if(blinker)`) through `System.Timers.Timer` and also tried the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` but messes up my Designer by not allowing me to set any of my properties when the control is added to a form and still does not fire up my drawing event. I did place `Invalidate(_Cursor)` in the `Tick` event to ensure that only the Cursor position is redrawn, even tried without the argument and still to no avail.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    if (Focused)
    {
        if (blinker)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(_CursorColor), _Cursor);
        foreach (Rectangle border in Borders)
        {
            if(_DrawBorders[Borders.IndexOf(border)])
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BorderColor), border);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I have also set

```
DoubleBuffered = true;
SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.Selectable | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | 
ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.StandardClick | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
```

Which helped with a terrible flickering and input issue I had.

`EDIT **(REMOVED AS IT IS FIXED USING COMMENT BY Hans Passant's SUGGESTION )**`

Okay, so now that the Timer is working, on to the problem I stated above. Drawing the Cursor.

```
    private void _CursorBlinkTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        blinker = !blinker;
        Console.WriteLine("Blink!");
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Height = TextRenderer.MeasureText("A", Font).Height + (2 * BorderWidth) + (2 * TextPadding);
        CursorPosition = (BorderWidth + TextPadding) + (_SelectedStart * (TextRenderer.MeasureText("_", Font).Width));
        _InputBounds = new Rectangle(BorderWidth + TextPadding, BorderWidth + TextPadding, Width - (2 * BorderWidth) - (2 * TextPadding), Height - (2 * BorderWidth));
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, new SolidBrush(TextColor), _InputBounds.Location);
        foreach (Rectangle border in Borders)
        {
            if (_DrawBorders[Borders.IndexOf(border)])
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(InactiveBorderColor), border);
        }

        if (Focused)
        {
            // This is where the Cursor is drawn, right before the borders.
            // I've tried to move it to after the border is drawn but same result, nothing is drawn.
            // I've ran through the entire OnPaint using Step-by-Step and while it does
            // fire the draw event, nothing is drawn.
            // BackColor = FromArgb(40,40,40), _CursorColor = Color.Red
            // _Cursor is a Rectangle that reads at this moment:
            // Rectangle(5,0,2,21) Which given all other variables should show result?
            if (blinker)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(_CursorColor), _Cursor);
            foreach (Rectangle border in Borders)
            {
                if(_DrawBorders[Borders.IndexOf(border)])
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BorderColor), border);
            }
        }
        else if (!Focused)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text))
                e.Graphics.DrawString(WaterMarkText, Font, new SolidBrush(WaterMarkColor), _InputBounds.Location);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So your problem is only in the VS Designer? you could add a condtion to starting the timer like this: `if( ! DesignMode) yourtimer.Start();`

Comment: The Timer itself is started only when the Control first gets Focus, then stopped when Focus is lost. Just the mere fact of adding the Timer to the class prevents me from using the VS Desinger, I'll add a screenshot of my Designer to Original post and add in.

Comment: The timer should be *static* so it can blink any instance of the control.  Best to create it (if null) and un/subscribe its Tick event in overloads for OnEnter/OnLeave().  Also ensures it never gets used at design time and cannot "mess" anything up.

Comment: I'll be honest, I have not thought of that. Let me try it.

Comment: @HansPassant It's definitely more efficient on the CPU and doesn't mess up my VS anymore, now just to get the drawing fixed. It seems that it is calling the Timer at proper intervals, but now the draw event doesn't show up. I'll edit original Post to add in.

Comment: When the Tick event handler changes the `blinker` variable then you have to also call `this.Invalidate();` to get the OnPaint() to run again.

Comment: It is there and `OnPaint()` is ran again when it is called.  Still no luck. I've used both `Invalidate()` and `Invalidate(_Cursor)` to see if they might yield different results by only drawing what's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after I decided to give up and stop trying, I removed every trace of the cursor I had, and started to look at drawing it again. Got that fixed. Then I went back to visit the Timers, and figured that when not using a class derived from a `System.Windows.Forms.Form`, the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` messes every ounce of what you think you had up. So, I moved on to the System.Timers.Timer (Which I had used previously on Mobile Development to great success).

All the problems I had are now resolved, thank you for your help yet again! I love this place.

Here is the code changes:

```
    private double _CursorInterval;
    /// <summary>
    /// Values below 500ms not recommended, due to safety hazards on epilepsy.
    /// </summary>
    public double CursorInterval
    {
        get { return _CursorInterval; }
        set { _CursorInterval = value; }
    }

    private bool blink = false;

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        Height = TextRenderer.MeasureText("A", Font).Height + (2 * BorderWidth) + (2 * TextPadding);
        _InputBounds = new Rectangle(BorderWidth + TextPadding, BorderWidth + TextPadding, Width - (2 * BorderWidth) - (2 * TextPadding), Height - (2 * BorderWidth) - (2 * TextPadding));

        if (blink)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BorderColor), new Rectangle(_InputBounds.Location, new Size(1, _InputBounds.Height)));
    }

    System.Timers.Timer blinkTimer;
    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            blinkTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(CursorInterval);
            blinkTimer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
            blinkTimer.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("OnGotFocus - I was here.");
        }
        blink = true;
        Invalidate();
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }

    private void TimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        blink = !blink;
        Console.WriteLine("TimerElapsed - I was here.");
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!DesignMode)
        {
            blink = false;
            blinkTimer.Stop();
            blinkTimer.Elapsed -= TimerElapsed;
            Console.WriteLine("OnLostFocus - I was here.");
        }
        Invalidate();
        base.OnLostFocus(e);
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
        Focus();
    }
```